# Is every finitely generated Kleinian group commensurable to a Coxeter group?

Tags: geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups, hyperbolic-groups

Or, to a finitely generated reflection group?  Here, I do not insist that the Coxeter group is represented as a hyperbolic reflection group.

If not, what is an counterexample? And what is a characterisation of Kleinian groups that are commensurable to a Coxeter group?

Comment: What do you mean by a Kleinian group? For instance, do arithmetic lattices in $PSL(2,C)$ qualify? What do you mean by a reflection group? In particular, what do you mean by a reflection (there are several competing viewpoints).

Comment: @studiosus: Kleinian group means discrete subgroup of hyperbolic isometries of ANY dimension.  Hyperbolic reflection group means group generated by reflections in Lorentz space / hyperbolic space.  Here, reflection carries the same meaning as in the canonical geometric representation of Coxeter groups.  However, I do not insist a Coxeter group to be represented as a reflection group, and a reflection group is not necessarily a Coxeter group.

Comment: Then the answer to your first question is negative (for reflection groups). The reason is that there are arithmetic Kleinian subgroups of $PSL(2,C)$ which contain no Fuchsian subgroups, it is somewhere in the book by Maclachlan and Reid "The Arithmetic of Hyperbolic 3-Manifolds". As for Coxeter groups - no idea (I suspect that it is hopelessly difficult).

Comment: Incidentally: What is your example of a discrete reflection group which is not isomorphic to a Coxeter group?

Comment: @studiosus: see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/148222/135000. Not sure if it's "discrete" in term of its action, but it's finitely generated.

Comment: @studiosus: no, the example in the link above is NOT discrete.  I think it's a theorem that discrete reflection groups are Coxeter groups.  But I do not insist on discreteness.

Comment: If you have a group $G$ commensurable to a discrete group $H$, then $G$ is automatically discrete. That's one reason I asked you about your definition of a Kleinian group.

Comment: You're right, I shall only talk about discrete groups.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer.

1. Suppose that $\Gamma< PSL(2,C)$ is a lattice which is commensurable to a reflection group. Then (by looking at the $\Gamma$-stabilizers of the mirrors of reflections), $\Gamma$ contains *Fuchsian subgroups* $\Lambda$. In this context, *Fuchsian* means that $\Lambda$ preserves a hyperplane $H<H^3$ and acts as a lattice on $H$. However, there are examples of arithmetic lattices without Fuchsian subgroups, see the book by Maclachlan and Reid "The Arithmetic of Hyperbolic 3-Manifolds", discussion on page 174, end of section 5.3.1.
2. A generic Fuchsian group uniformizing a genus 3 hyperbolic surface will be maximal discrete Fuchsian groups, hence , not commensurable to a group with torsion, hence, not commensurable to a Coxeter group.
3. Having a criterion seems very hard/hopeless (to me): Each time you have a non-tautological criterion for something complicated, you probably proved a deep theorem.

Comment: Point 2 helped, thanks.

Comment: Wait...isn't every finitely generated Kleinian group virtually torsion free?

Comment: @Hao: Yes, did I say otherwise?

Comment: Coxeter groups are also virtually torsion free.  Not sure what do you mean in point 2.

Comment: @HaoCHEN: Suppose you have two discrete commensurable subgroups $A, B$ in a Lie group $G$. The subgroups $A,B$ generate a discrete subgroup $C$ of $G$. If $B$ has torsion, so does $C$; if $A$ were torsion-free, and a  maximal discrete subgroup of $G$, you get a contradiction. The fact that $B$ happens to be virtually torsion-free is irrelevant. Is it all clear now?

Comment: Ok, didn't get the word "asking", thanks.